# Hive error on all queries: Couldn't find log associated with operation handle

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

Getting an error on all hive queries running on Hadoop.

Simply running a select statement from a table that exists and getting the following results:

```
Fetching results ran into the following error(s):

Couldn't find log associated with operation handle: 
OperationHandle[opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT,
getHandleIdentifier()=263df9c3-c076-454f-a025-23f5b919e957]
```

And the accompaning logs for the query are:

> Bad status for request TFetchResultsReq(fetchType=1,
>   operationHandle=TOperationHandle(hasResultSet=False,
>   modifiedRowCount=None, operationType=0,
>   operationId=THandleIdentifier(secret='%\x1d\x0f\x11\xce\xf4B\xd6\xb8\xb5\x8ddv\xceKV',
>   guid="\xbc5\xd9|\xfa\x13J'\x86\x8e4\xb3\x87\xa0\xf4\x05")),
>   orientation=4, maxRows=-1):
>   TFetchResultsResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=0, errorMessage="Couldn't
>   find log associated with operation handle: OperationHandle
>   [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT,
>   getHandleIdentifier()=bc35d97c-fa13-4a27-868e-34b387a0f405]",
>   sqlState=None,
>   infoMessages=["*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Couldn't
>   find log associated with operation handle: OperationHandle
>   [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT,
>   getHandleIdentifier()=bc35d97c-fa13-4a27-868e-34b387a0f405]:25:24",
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager:getOperationLogRowSet:OperationManager.java:257',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:fetchResults:HiveSessionImpl.java:656',
>   'sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29:invoke::-1',
>   'sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43',
>   'java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:Method.java:606',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:79',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:access$000:HiveSessionProxy.java:37',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1:run:HiveSessionProxy.java:64',
>   'java.security.AccessController:doPrivileged:AccessController.java:-2',
>   'javax.security.auth.Subject:doAs:Subject.java:415',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:doAs:UserGroupInformation.java:1628',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure:doAs:HadoopShimsSecure.java:536',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:60',
>   'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28:fetchResults::-1',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:fetchResults:CLIService.java:427',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:FetchResults:ThriftCLIService.java:587',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1553',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1538',
>   'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39',
>   'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56',
>   'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:206',
>   'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145',
>   'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615',
>   'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:744'], statusCode=3), results=None,
>   hasMoreRows=None) Bad status for request TFetchResultsReq(fetchType=1,
>   operationHandle=TOperationHandle(hasResultSet=False,
>   modifiedRowCount=None, operationType=0,
>   operationId=THandleIdentifier(secret='c\xdf\xfe\xb7\x8a\x10D\xea\xbaD\x93}B\xb5\xc3\xe7',
>   guid='&=\xf9\xc3\xc0vEO\xa0%#\xf5\xb9\x19\xe9W')), orientation=0,
>   maxRows=-1): TFetchResultsResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=0,
>   errorMessage="Couldn't find log associated with operation handle:
>   OperationHandle [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT,
>   getHandleIdentifier()=263df9c3-c076-454f-a025-23f5b919e957]",
>   sqlState=None,
>   infoMessages=["*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Couldn't
>   find log associated with operation handle: OperationHandle
>   [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT,
>   getHandleIdentifier()=263df9c3-c076-454f-a025-23f5b919e957]:25:24",
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager:getOperationLogRowSet:OperationManager.java:257',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:fetchResults:HiveSessionImpl.java:656',
>   'sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29:invoke::-1',
>   'sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43',
>   'java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:Method.java:606',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:79',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:access$000:HiveSessionProxy.java:37',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1:run:HiveSessionProxy.java:64',
>   'java.security.AccessController:doPrivileged:AccessController.java:-2',
>   'javax.security.auth.Subject:doAs:Subject.java:415',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:doAs:UserGroupInformation.java:1628',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure:doAs:HadoopShimsSecure.java:536',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:60',
>   'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28:fetchResults::-1',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:fetchResults:CLIService.java:427',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:FetchResults:ThriftCLIService.java:587',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1553',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1538',
>   'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39',
>   'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56',
>   'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:206',
>   'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145',
>   'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615',
>   'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:744'], statusCode=3), results=None,
>   hasMoreRows=None) Bad status for request TFetchResultsReq(fetchType=1,
>   operationHandle=TOperationHandle(hasResultSet=False,
>   modifiedRowCount=None, operationType=0,
>   operationId=THandleIdentifier(secret='c\xdf\xfe\xb7\x8a\x10D\xea\xbaD\x93}B\xb5\xc3\xe7',
>   guid='&=\xf9\xc3\xc0vEO\xa0%#\xf5\xb9\x19\xe9W')), orientation=0,
>   maxRows=-1): TFetchResultsResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=0,
>   errorMessage="Couldn't find log associated with operation handle:
>   OperationHandle [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT,
>   getHandleIdentifier()=263df9c3-c076-454f-a025-23f5b919e957]",
>   sqlState=None,
>   infoMessages=["*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Couldn't
>   find log associated with operation handle: OperationHandle
>   [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT,
>   getHandleIdentifier()=263df9c3-c076-454f-a025-23f5b919e957]:25:24",
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager:getOperationLogRowSet:OperationManager.java:257',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:fetchResults:HiveSessionImpl.java:656',
>   'sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29:invoke::-1',
>   'sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43',
>   'java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:Method.java:606',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:79',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:access$000:HiveSessionProxy.java:37',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1:run:HiveSessionProxy.java:64',
>   'java.security.AccessController:doPrivileged:AccessController.java:-2',
>   'javax.security.auth.Subject:doAs:Subject.java:415',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:doAs:UserGroupInformation.java:1628',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure:doAs:HadoopShimsSecure.java:536',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:60',
>   'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28:fetchResults::-1',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:fetchResults:CLIService.java:427',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:FetchResults:ThriftCLIService.java:587',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1553',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1538',
>   'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39',
>   'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56',
>   'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:206',
>   'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145',
>   'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615',
>   'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:744'], statusCode=3), results=None,
>   hasMoreRows=None)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error can happen with the **i.e(“hive.server2.logging.operation.log.location”)** is pointing to a location that does not exist to write logs.

Look at the code from **OperationManager.java**

```
OperationLog operationLog = getOperation(opHandle).getOperationLog();
if (operationLog == null) {
  throw new HiveSQLException("Couldn't find log associated with operation handle: " + opHandle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I go about checking where / changing where it is pointed to?

Comment: Follow this link to know configure log file location. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration#AdminManualConfiguration-LogFiles

Comment: Generally this is caused by due to connection string issue, I have faced similar issues and generally once I corrected my connection string: jdbc://hive2:<servername>:port/default, the issue gets resolved.

Answer (score 12):

If you are seeing this in a Cloudera distro when you use Hue, then add the following to the *Hive Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hive-site.xml* in Cloudera Manager (or straight to the hive-site.xml for other distros):

```
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.logging.operation.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AWS EMR, then add the following to the hive-site.xml file at `/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-site.xml`:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.logging.operation.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Then log into the master node and restart hue and hive server

```
sudo stop hive-server2
sudo stop hue
sudo start hue
sudo start hive-server2
```

This fixed it for me (tested in Release label `emr-4.6.0`).

Answer (score 1):

If you're running into this issue due to a shell script or java program, the first thing you need to check is the connection string, I have faced similar issue few months back, when in my script I was running the queries in such manner:

```
beeline -u  jdbc:hive2:// -e "show databases;"
```

This was due to missing of proper Hive Connection string, once I corrected the connection string and ran the query, it ran without any issues:

```
beeline -u  jdbc:hive2://server.enterprise.org:10000/default -e "show databases;"
```

This answer is only specific to the developers who are using a script or code, for Hue/Cloudera distro, kindly refer to the above answers.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8.1, I were also facing the same issue part inside `hive` query part -

```
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Couldn't find log associated with operation handle: OperationHandle [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT, getHandleIdentifier()=230485c4-a1be-4a17-94c8-a1ebce426319]
```

thus, I went to the `%HIVE_HOME%/conf/hive-site.xml` and changed the property name `hive.server2.logging.operation.log.location` earlier value `${system:user.name}/operation_logs` to like below said -

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.logging.operation.log.location</name>
    <value>/tmp/${user.name}/operation_logs</value>
    <description>Top level directory where operation logs are stored if logging functionality is enabled</description>
  </property>
```

and also replaced all the values which contains the `${system:user.name}` to `/tmp/${user.name}` and this brings me up by the job logging issue in hive, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure you can use

```
    beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://headnodehost:10001/;transportMode=http'
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating the table use the following code -

```
Create external table if not exists TEST1 
(
col1 string,
col2 int,
col3 date
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim'=',') 
location 'hdfs:/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Choose whether to use the old GetLog() thrift call from before Hive 0.14 to retrieve the logs.
If false, use the FetchResults() thrift call from Hive 1.0 or more instead

**use_get_log_api=false**

change true for false