# ThriftCLIService: Error fetching results

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, thrift, apache-spark-sql

Any idea why in my log: `spark-ubuntu-org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2-1-group-3-vm1.out` I see this?

```
02:19:16 WARN ThriftCLIService: Error fetching results:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Couldn't find log associated with operation handle: OperationHandle [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT, getHandleIdentifier()=2ea77d80-34f7-4b00-a8f1-7d544e9317a5]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager.getOperationLogRowSet(OperationManager.java:229)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.fetchResults(HiveSessionImpl.java:687)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:78)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:36)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:63)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.fetchResults(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.fetchResults(CLIService.java:454)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.FetchResults(ThriftCLIService.java:672)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults.getResult(TCLIService.java:1553)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults.getResult(TCLIService.java:1538)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:285)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
~
```

Comment: refer to this:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090918/hive-error-on-all-queries-couldnt-find-log-associated-with-operation-handle).

Comment: looks like a bug : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11043